# ListBox selection Removed when item of other listbox selected

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, controls, itemscontrol

I have created one WPF user control having two list boxes.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}"
                             Style="{DynamicResource ProductListBoxStyle}"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColor, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Margin="0,40,0,0"
                             ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ProductListColorItemContainerStyle}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <StaticResource ResourceKey="ItemsDetailsTemplate" />
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListBox>


                    <ListBox Grid.Row="1"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentProduct.DimensionAttributes}"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDimention, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                             Style="{DynamicResource ProductListBoxStyle}"
                             ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ProductListItemContainerStyle}"
                             Margin="0,40">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <StaticResource ResourceKey="SizeTemplate" />
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListBox>
```

But the problem is when I select one item from color then if I try to select one size >the selection from Color is removed. why it is so?

Comment: Are you probably confusing the selected item with the one that has the focus?

Comment: Agreed, selection shouldn't be affected by this. If it is, then you must be doing something to `SelectedColor` in your ViewModel.

Comment: Mind to show us your `ProductListColorItemContainerStyle` and `ProductListItemContainerStyle`?